# What is "DbContextOptions`1"?

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, dependency-injection, entity-framework-core

I have Web API in **ASP .NET Core**. When I add a db context in `Startup.ConfigureServices`:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddDbContext<FixturesContext>(
            options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("FixturesDatabase")));
    services.AddControllers();
}
```

I see the number of services in the "services" container raises by three, I think those are:

- FixturesContext
- DbContextOptions
- DbContextOptions`1

I am curious what is `"DbContextOptions1"`? Does anyone know? I have tried googling it but not satysfying result. My goal is to replace original context with in-memory (to run integration tests without original database), so I'm deleting db context and its options and adding in-memory context instead of them.

Comment: Check the docs here for more details https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/configuring-dbcontext#configuring-dbcontextoptions

Comment: It would be the generic  `DbContextOptions<FixturesContext>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The third service you are getting is a generic version of the DbContextOptions. When calling `.ToString()` on a generic type it often looks like this.

The reason why there are three instances is that EF adds a general DbContextOptions object and a more specific one for your defined context.

If you inspect the calls of the third service you should find the type of your DbContext as a generic parameter.

Answer (score 3):

`DbContextOptions'1` would be the generic  `DbContextOptions<FixturesContext>` registered to be injected into the context when being initialized.

Reference [Configuring DbContextOptions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/configuring-dbcontext#configuring-dbcontextoptions)

```
public class FixturesContext : DbContext
{
    public FixturesContext(DbContextOptions<FixturesContext> options)
        : base(options)
    { }

    //...
}
```